# Preg_Match c/ Expressão regular

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

preciso remover tudo o que estiver ao redor do link abaixo.
Estou usando o preg_match com expressão regular, e como sou novo na área, estou com dificuldade para achar o meu erro.
Poderiam me ajudar por gentileza?

Como estou fazendo:

```
preg_match('/www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=\/(.+)&show_text=0&width=560', $v, $output
```

Link completo: https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fportateste%2Fvideos%2F1585186298555265%2F&show_text=0&width=560

Preciso: "https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fportateste%2Fvideos%2F1585186298555265%2F"

Obrigado

Comment: Você pode tentar obter o que está no grupo desta regex: `href=(.+)(?=&show_text)`, em que [aqui está a demo](https://regex101.com/r/qhcjWz/1/). Como não possuo experiência em php, não sei a programação. Mas esta regex captura o grupo que está entre `href=` e `&show_text`

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a seguinte expressão:

```
href=(.*?)&
```

Dessa forma ele vai capturar tudo que tiver entre `href`, até o primeiro `&`.

Exemplo:

```
<?php

preg_match("/href=(.*?)&/", $link, $result);

var_dump( $result[1] );
```

[**Demonstração**](https://regex101.com/r/iVjnpU/1)

Caso você queira algo mais complexo, basta utilizar a expressão abaixo:

```
href=(.*?)(?(?=&)&|$)
     └─┬─┘ └┬─┘└┬┘└┬┘
       │    │   │  └── Caso não haja, selecione até o último caractere.
       │    │   └───── Caso haja, seleciona até ele.
       │    └───────── Verifique se há `&` na URL
       └────────────── Captura tudo após o `href=`
```

[**Demonstração**](https://regex101.com/r/iVjnpU/3)